# Racket Iterations and Recursion

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

```
(define (diagonal? col a)
 (cond
   [(null? a) #f]
   [(= (abs(- (car a) col)) (abs (- (+ (length a) 1) (length a))))]
   [else #f]))
```

I want this to check the second condition repetitively on the list a and only return true or false if it has reached the end of the list. I also do not want it to change the list a at all.

I want to get

```
>(iQueens '(1 2 3 4) '())
> (iQueens '(2 3 4) '(1))
> >(iQueens '(2 4) '(3 1))
< <'()
> >(iQueens '(2 3) '(4 1))
> >(iQueens '(3) '(2 4 1))
< < '()
< <'()
< '()
```

But I am getting

```
>(iQueens '(1 2 3 4) '())
> (iQueens '(2 3 4) '(1))
> >(iQueens '(2 4) '(3 1))
< <'()
> >(iQueens '(2 3) '(4 1))
< <'()
< '()
```

Input/Output Including "diagonal?"

```
>(iQueens '(1 2 3 4) '())
> (diagonal? 1 '())
< #f
> (iQueens '(2 3 4) '(1))
> >(diagonal? 2 '(1))
< <#t
> >(diagonal? 3 '(1))
> >(diagonal? 3 '())
< <#f
> >(iQueens '(2 4) '(3 1))
> > (diagonal? 2 '(3 1))
< < #t
> > (diagonal? 4 '(3 1))
< < #t
< <'()
> >(diagonal? 4 '(1))
> >(diagonal? 4 '())
< <#f
> >(iQueens '(2 3) '(4 1))
> > (diagonal? 2 '(4 1))
> > (diagonal? 2 '(1))
< < #t
> > (diagonal? 3 '(4 1))
< < #t
< <'()
< '()
> (diagonal? 2 '())
< #f
> (iQueens '(1 3 4) '(2))
> >(diagonal? 1 '(2))
< <#t
> >(diagonal? 3 '(2))
< <#t
> >(diagonal? 4 '(2))
> >(diagonal? 4 '())
< <#f
> >(iQueens '(1 3) '(4 2))
> > (diagonal? 1 '(4 2))
> > (diagonal? 1 '(2))
< < #t
> > (diagonal? 3 '(4 2))
< < #t
< <'()
< '()
> (diagonal? 3 '())
< #f
> (iQueens '(1 2 4) '(3))
> >(diagonal? 1 '(3))
> >(diagonal? 1 '())
< <#f
> >(iQueens '(2 4) '(1 3))
> > (diagonal? 2 '(1 3))
< < #t
> > (diagonal? 4 '(1 3))
> > (diagonal? 4 '(3))
< < #t
< <'()
> >(diagonal? 2 '(3))
< <#t
> >(diagonal? 4 '(3))
< <#t
< '()
> (diagonal? 4 '())
< #f
> (iQueens '(1 2 3) '(4))
> >(diagonal? 1 '(4))
> >(diagonal? 1 '())
< <#f
> >(iQueens '(2 3) '(1 4))
> > (diagonal? 2 '(1 4))
< < #t
> > (diagonal? 3 '(1 4))
> > (diagonal? 3 '(4))
< < #t
< <'()
> >(diagonal? 2 '(4))
> >(diagonal? 2 '())
< <#f
> >(iQueens '(1 3) '(2 4))
> > (diagonal? 1 '(2 4))
< < #t
> > (diagonal? 3 '(2 4))
< < #t
< <'()
> >(diagonal? 3 '(4))
< <#t
< '()
<'()
0
```

I think I finally understand that my logic behind that condition is incorrect. But the logic makes sense to me on paper. Can you offer me a hint at where I am going wrong with the logic in the second part of the condition? I was so held up on the output being so similar to the answer that I needed. I figured that my code had to be wrong, not my logic.

*Edit

```
(define (diagonal? col a count)
 (if
   (null? a) 
   #f
   (if(or (= (car a) (+ col count)) (= (car a) (- col count)))
    #t
(diagonal? col (cdr a) (+ 1 count))
)))
```

This logic works... but I was forced to use count... I still can't figure out how I can change this to not use the third parameter I was trying to avoid.

*Edit

To get the diagonals above to work I used

```
(λ(x) (if(not (diagonal? x a 1) )
                (iQueens (remove x l) (cons x a))
                '()))
                 l)))
```

The call for what I want is

```
(λ(x) (cond
           [(diagonal? x a) (cdr l) '()]
           [else (iQueens (remove x l) (cons x a))]))l)))
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what the second condition is supposed to do? does it have to be true for all elements in the list, or is enough if it's true just for one? We don't know the contents of `a`, you should post a sample input with expected output for one case when this procedure returns true, and one when it returns false

Comment: Do you mean that procedure `diagonal` does not call itself? Indeed it doesn't, since there is no call to `diagonal` in the procedure. Is `a` the list?

Comment: Please edit your question and trim it down to the *essential*: one or a limited number of representative input data you have, your procedure, and for each input the expected output and the output you get instead.

Comment: So what is the meaning of `(diagonals? 2 '(4 1))`. Does it mean "is (row 2 column 2) in the same diagonals than (row 0 column 4) and (row 1 column 1)"?

Comment: in your diagonal you subtract (length a)+1 from length a. that would be always 1. how are queens represented in your program? as @uselpa Said. you aren't calling diagonal so it can't recur.

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't given example input and output for `diagonal?`, but here's my try:

```
(define (diagonal? col len elt)
  (= (abs (- elt col)) 
     (abs (- (+ len 1) len)))) ; this is constant 1

(define (diagonals? col lst)
  (define len (length lst))
  (andmap (lambda (elt) (diagonal? len col elt)) lst))
```

`diagonal?` operates on one element only, and `diagonals?` processes the whole list.

As you see, the expression `(abs (- (+ len 1) len)))` is actually the constant `1` so this is probably not correct in your initial procedure. Also, I assumed you want that *all* elements of the list should verify the predicate, otherwise you'd have to use `ormap` instead of `andmap`.

```
> (diagonals? 2 '(4 1))
#f
```

**EDIT**

I can only guess, given that you don't give enough information, but maybe this helps, assuming count starts at 0 (if not, just change the `in-naturals`call):

```
(define (diagonal? col a)
  (for/or ((i (in-list a)) (count (in-naturals)))
    (or (= i (+ col count)) (= i (- col count)))))
```

Comment: Ok I have figured it out using a third parameter. Am I able to change this to work in racket with only the two original parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/index.html) (the language) and not Scheme or Common Lisp (which scheme and lisp your tags indicate) you can just supply a default value:

```
(define (diagonal? col a (count 0))
  (cond ((null? a) #f)
        ((or (= (car a) (+ col count)) 
             (= (car a) (- col count)))
         #t)
        (else (diagonal? col (cdr a) (+ 1 count)))))
```

In [Scheme](http://www.r6rs.org/) (a different language than racket also supported by racket implementation) there are 2 ways to expose a procedure with less arguments than what you use in your recursive procedure. One is local procedures:

```
(define (diagonal? col a)
  (define (diagonal? col a count)
    (cond ((null? a) #f)
          ((or (= (car a) (+ col count)) 
               (= (car a) (- col count)))
           #t)
          (else (diagonal? col (cdr a) (+ 1 count)))))
  (diagonal? col a 0)) ;; add default values
```

Or you can use a named let:

```
(define (diagonal? col a)
  (let diagonal? ((col col) (a a) (count 0))
    (cond ((null? a) #f)
          ((or (= (car a) (+ col count)) 
               (= (car a) (- col count)))
           #t)
          (else (diagonal? col (cdr a) (+ 1 count))))))
```

This is just syntactic sugar for the first Scheme example. Racket (the language) supports both these too.

In [Lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/) you have optional arguments again:

```
(defun diagonalp (col a &optional (count 0))
  (cond ((null a) nil)
        ((or (= (car a) (+ col count)) 
             (= (car a) (- col count)))
         t)
        (t (diagonalp col (cdr a) (+ 1 count)))))
```

This is just a simpler way to make and use a procedure. In both cases you make a local procedure with the same name as the exposed procedure. Some people want to use different names or use aux postfix. This is just difference in taste as long as you don't need to call both the local and global version.